# How to iterate over possible values over values of a column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table, which stores names and numbers associated with it. Each of these numbers are of a certain type. The combination of name and type is unique.

```
 name | type | number
---------------------
 a    | t0   | 5
 a    | t1   | 6
 b    | t0   | 7
 c    | t1   | 8
```

And I want this table as a result, which shows the numbers which are associated with that name, regardless of type accumulated.

```
 name | sum
------------
 a    | 11
 c    | 8
 b    | 7
```

Now I know the `SUM()` function and I have written this so far:

```
SELECT name, SUM( ??SELECT name, SUM(number) WHERE name = 'a'?? ) AS sum
FROM table
ORDER BY sum DESC;
```

The thing is I don't know how to write the inner part of the `SUM()` function, as I can't use `SELECT` statements inside of functions. Also I don't know how I can iterate over the possible values of the name column.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `GROUP BY` along with `SUM`:

```
SELECT name, SUM(number) AS sum
FROM tableName
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY SUM(number) DESC;  -- or ORDER BY sum DESC; - it is identical
```

Comment: Why can't it be `ORDER BY sum DESC`?

Comment: Because the query does not know it as sum yet. just as Sum(number). If you query this query then it's name is Sum. In this query it's getting a new name for outside this query.

Comment: Why does the `AS sum` bit not declare it as *sum*?

Comment: That's strange. Are there any performance implications? Will it try to do the `SUM` more than once?

Comment: Tables allow you to use their alias within the same query, but fields just don't work that way. I'm not sure why, but I think that's more confusing. I like it the way it is :)

Comment: The query is basic and it will execute fine. It depends on your data though. And indexes.

Comment: You should up vote me too because we have the same query and I need reputation :) please

Comment: You can use both `SUM(number)` and `sum` in `ORDER BY` statement - both result and execution will be the same

Comment: @dotnetom Wow that's new to me and I decided to try it. It appears using the alias does in fact work and is actually faster. This makes me believe the aggregate may be executed twice. With a large table I am seeing a difference in execution time, but the same execution plan.

Comment: @MichaelZ. I'm not sure about MySQL, but SQL Server produces the same execution plan in both cases, so performance is identical in both cases. It could be that MySQL executes this somewhat differently.

Comment: Well anyway, this is why I like this site. I learn stuff every day. Thanks @dotnetom

Comment: @dotnetom so same thing for Group By right? Let me ask you this though...why do you default to the function in the order by? Is this fairly new to SQL?

Comment: @MichaelZ. In group by you need to specify the column that you group by, so you must specify `name` there. And I've used function, because I was not sure MySQL supports aliases in `ORDER BY` statement (apparently it does).

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT NAME, 
       Sum(number) As 'Sum'
FROM   table 
GROUP  BY NAME 
ORDER  BY Sum(number) DESC;
```